# Why dataframe.shape[0] prints an integer, but dataframe.columnname.shape prints a tuple

Tags: python, pandas

Just curious.

I have some data I am working with, and when I input

```
train.Id.shape
```

python returned `(1467,)` - a tuple

but when I input

```
train.shape[0]
```

python returned `1467` - an integer

Curious how Pandas handles these two different inputs, and why they are different.
Is this a specific feature, or just a quirk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`train.Id` is a pandas Series and is one dimensional.  `train` is a pandas DataFrame and is two dimensional.  `shape` is an attribute that both DataFrames and Series have.  It is always a tuple.  For a Series the tuple has only only value `(x,)`.  For a DataFrame shape is a tuple with two values `(x, y)`.  So `train.Id.shape[0]` would also return `1467`.  However, `train.Id.shape[1]` would produce an error while `train.shape[1]` would give you the number of columns in `train`.

Furthermore, pandas Panel objects are three dimensional and `shape` for it returns a tuple `(x, y, z)`

```
train = pd.DataFrame(dict(Id=np.arange(1437), A=np.arange(1437)))

print(train.shape)
print(train.Id.shape)

(1437, 2)
(1437,)
```

Comment: Thanks for the concise explanation!